# Refactoring PHP OOP - How to get the object without passing a parameter?

Tags: php, oop, refactoring

I need to refactor this code to not use a parameter when using the "save()" method.

The code is:

Person.php

```
class Person {

    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $country;

    public function save($object) {

        $api = new ReflectionClass($object);

        foreach($api->getProperties() as $propertie)
        {
            print $propertie->getName() . " - " . $propertie->getValue($object) . " | ";    
        }       
    }

}

?>
```

Example_usage.php

```
include_once('person.php');

$p = new Person();

$p->name = 'Mary';
$p->age = '28';
$p->country = 'Italy';
$p->save($p);

?>
```

My question. How can I use the "save()" method like this:

```
$p->save();
```

It is possible to pass the $p object in other way than passing the parameter in the "save()" method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ReflectionClass` for this purpose.

```
public function save() {
    echo $this->name; //etc
    // or maybe

    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($this->name);
    $age = ...
    $country = ... 

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO persons (name, age, country) values ('$name', '$age', '$country')");
}
```

If you would like to get each variable name together with its value, it's as easy this:

```
class test {
        public $key = 2;
        public $star = 'sun';
        private $planet = 'earth';

        public function save() {
                foreach($this as $key => $value) {
                         echo "$key => $value".PHP_EOL;
                }
        }

}

$t = new test();
$t->save();
```

Comment: 1. Example does not store in a database. 2. Prepared statements. Learn them. 3. PDO.

Comment: @Cthulhu: 1. "or maybe" -> I was trying to be helpful to expand the scope of the solution since a method called `save()` probably means "make persistant", where a database is proper. Right? 2. It's a bit out of this question's scope, don't you think? I used that line of escaping mechanism *in case* the author would drop the suggestion into a live app. At least it would be somewhat protecting. 3. I prefer Zend_Db and Doctrine, try them out, you would like them.

Comment: @Cthulhu: how do you feel about the use of `ReflectionClass` in the question? *sic*

Comment: Hi, I will use save() to store information to a Database. I'm trying the ReflectionClass because the database model is not very commom

Comment: @chelmertz, the overview of this question is in this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993080/php-class-how-to-structure-a-method-to-save-data-to-the-database But I haven't received any reply, and I'm trying out to see what will work in this situation.

Comment: @André: what about my first example? It contains how you get your class' variables & their keys for manual insertion, combine it with the second example if you wish all your properties to represent a row of your database table. You should probably google for `Active Record` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your second example could fit in what I need. Best Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Current object is available with `$this` keyword you don't need to pass object just use `$this` inside the class method to point that object in your case `$p`

Modified method will look like this

```
public function save() {

        $api = new ReflectionClass($this);

        foreach($api->getProperties() as $propertie)
        {
            print $propertie->getName() . " - " . $propertie->getValue($this) . " | ";    
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This actually will do what I want to do. Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Do you always want to pass the instance of the `Person` class from which you are calling the save method to the `ReflectionClass`?
Then you can also just pass `$this` which always references to the instance of the class.

Comment: 666: could you post a case of when is viable to pass `$this` to an instance of the same class? Why should that be preferred instead of just using `$this` inside of the current instance?

Comment: I meant it like Shakti Singh answered it (maybe a bit better explained). Inside the Person class he should just pass ```$this``` instead of handing the instance of the ```Person``` class from outside to the save method.